# How to let the query parameter "type" overwrite the PageTypeDecorator Settings?

Tags: routes, typo3, typo3-9.x

In my setup it is required that I can override the page `type` by query parameter. A change here is conceptually not possible.

As basis I have a TYPO3 9 LTS with the following PageType configuration:

```
  PageTypeSuffix:
    type: PageType
    default: '.html'
    index: 'home
    map:
      '.xml': 3536236
      'sitemap.xml': 123456
```

The following calls sets the correct `type=3536236`

- *.local/en/test?type=3536236
- *.local/en/test.xml

What I need is the following one:

- *.local/en/test.html?type=3536236
  This acutally sets only `type=0` since the decorator settings matches.

The `type` parameter must have a higher value here.

The crucial place in the code is here:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Routing\PageRouter::resolveType
```

Here the `_decoratedParameters` overwrite a possibly set query parameter.
My current solution is an XClass, which changes this behaviour.

Further considerations went towards custom routeEnhancer or PageTypeDecorator.
Unfortunately I don't find the right place to assume that this behaviour only applies when interpreting the request.

Maybe someone has an idea?

---

**Solution:**
Currently I use the solution suggested in Slack (https://typo3.slack.com/archives/C025BQLFA/p1598950920293600) and manipulate the request uri with a middleware like:

```
public function process(
    ServerRequestInterface $request,
    RequestHandlerInterface $handler
): ResponseInterface {                
    $uri = $request->getUri();
    $uriPath = rtrim($uri->getPath(), '.html');

    $uri = $uri->withPath($uriPath);

    $request = $request->withUri($uri);

    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_REQUEST'] = $request;
    return $handler->handle($request);
}
```

This works very well!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an XCLASS. You can write a custom route enhancer for your needs: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Routing/ExtendingRouting.html